# JavaFX 8 - Property "about to change" somehow?

Tags: properties, notifications, javafx-8

I need to add some validation to my JavaFX8 application.
In order to effectively do this I would need to hook somewhere in the various Controls **before** content is actually changed and conditionally inhibiting the change (and doing some error reporting, of course).

The normal way (attaching a ChangeListener to the relevant Property) actually arrives far too late and, if validation fails, I need to undo last change, which is messy, error prone and spawns more (unwanted) ChangeEvents.

Is there some way of getting notification "about to change"?

Alternatively: what is the "Best Practice" for Validation?

I did some research, but it doesn't seem there's anything available, even jidefx defines, but does not implement `REVERT` `FailBehavior`,

Comment: Not sure, maybe you can use [inhibeans](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX/wiki/InhiBeans).

Comment: chain an adapter between the two properties and do the validation on the adapter